# Figuring out the right struct to parse a simple YAML file in Golang

Tags: go, yaml

I have a fairly simple YAML document to parse into a (preferably) map in Go.

YAML doc:

```
---
A: Logon
'0': Heartbeat
'1': Test Request
'2': Resend Request
'3': Reject
'4': Sequence Reset
'5': Logout
'8': Execution Report
S: Quote
AE: Trade Capture Report
B: News
h: Trading Session Status
f: Security Status
```

I'm trying to marshal it with

```
type TranslationVal struct {
    Map map[string]string
}

translationVal := TranslationVal{}
err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(val), &translationVal)
```

However I'm getting:

```
2017/08/22 20:33:23 yaml: unmarshal errors:   line 1: cannot unmarshal !!str `A` into main.TranslationVal
```

Comment: What library are you using to parse the YAML?

Comment: @Adrian https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by you wrapping the map in an object, the YAML has no such nesting.

```
map := map[string]string{}
err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(val), &map)
```

You can actually just unmarshal directly into the map itself

EDIT: hard to tell with your formatting but if those integer keys are nested under `A` then you will need a different structure as well, it would actually be a `map[string]map[string]string` -- however that is rather ugly so I would recommend moving to a different paradigm at that point... You could either use a `map[string]interface{}` which wouldn't care what types go into the map and then you could deal with it later or you could define the object more statically, using actually keys such a `A` in a struct to denote where each item goes, if that were the case you'd have an object like the following;

```
type TranslationVal struct {
    A map[string]string
    B string
    C string
    // and so on
    F string `yaml:f` // necessary because f would be unexported
}
```

Comment: there is no nesting in YAML sample I provided. Unfortunately, your suggested solution of using map[string]string{} directly doesn't work and produces the same error: `line 1: cannot unmarshal !!str 'A' into map[string]string`

Answer (score -1):

I actually tried to parse a value that wasn't YAML at all, doh!!